# Click event on moving a image

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an image(ball) its a BitmapDrawable and it moves in all directions on the screen for that i am taking onDraw(canvas) in AnimatedView.java its working fine.

**My Requirement:** 
I want to click on the image, but unfortunately the whole screen takes the event.

Please help me.

How to get click event only on the image?
So that i can proceed with further development.

Here is the code:

```
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;
    int count=0;
    EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AnimatedView animatedView=(AnimatedView) findViewById(R.id.anim_view);
        animatedView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ball);
                 v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.animation));


            }
        });

animatedview.java:

public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{

    private Context mContext;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    private int xVelocity = 10;
    private int yVelocity = 5;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 30;
    BitmapDrawable ball;

    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
        super(context, attrs);  
        mContext = context;  
        h = new Handler();
    } 

    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate(); 
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

        BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
        if (x<0 && y <0) {
            x = this.getWidth()/2;
            y = this.getHeight()/2;
        } else {
            x += xVelocity;
            y += yVelocity;
            if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
            }
            if ((y > this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) || (y < 0)) {
                yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
            }
        }
        c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    

    }


main.xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">

<com.example.example.AnimatedView
        android:id="@+id/anim_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:onClick="imageClicked" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**I hope This codes Works for you, what you are looking for.....**

This is the complete code representing both ball movement and touch on ball.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
    BubbleGraphic bubbleGraphic;
    int bm_x = 0, bm_y = 0, bm_offsetx, bm_offsety, bm_w, bm_h, subBM_w, subBM_h;
    int f = 0;
    private float x, y;
    Canvas canvas;
    boolean dm_touched = false;
    static int random_x;
    static int random_y;
    boolean touching;

    // These variable for position in x_axis direction
    int w1;

    // These variable for position in y_axis direction
    int h1;

    // These variable for velocity in x_axis direction
    private int w1_V;

    // These variable for velocity in y_axis direction
    private int h1_V;

    Bitmap mainBG;
    Bitmap bmpBall;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bubbleGraphic = new BubbleGraphic(this);
        bubbleGraphic.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // Your Background Image of Canvas
        mainBG = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg1);

        w1 = -1;
        h1 = -1;
        w1_V = 1;
        h1_V = 1;

        // This is used to create bitmap object and decode the input stream into bitmap
        bmpBall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.myBall);

        bm_w = bmpBall.getWidth();
        bm_h = bmpBall.getHeight();

        setContentView(bubbleGraphic);

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        bubbleGraphic.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bubbleGraphic.resume();
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            touching = true;

            if (dm_touched) {
                w1 = (int) x - bm_offsetx;
                h1 = (int) y - bm_offsety;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            touching = true;

            // checking if Ball is touched
            if ((x > w1) && (x < bm_w + w1) && (y > h1) && (y < bm_h + h1)) {
                bm_offsetx = (int) x - w1;
                bm_offsety = (int) y - h1;
            }

            dm_touched = true;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        default:

            dm_touched = false;
            touching = false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // **************************************************************************************//
    // Creating Canvas graphic Class and running thread //
    // *************************************************************************************//

    class BubbleGraphic extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        Thread thread = null;
        boolean isRunning = false;
        boolean holdingBubble = true;
        private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        public BubbleGraphic(Context context) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        public void pause() {
            isRunning = false;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                break;
            }
            thread = null;
        }

        public void resume() {
            isRunning = true;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();`enter code here`

                canvas.drawBitmap(mainBG, 0, 0, null);

                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                if (touching) {
                    canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + bm_w, y + bm_h, paint);
                }

                canvas.drawBitmap(bmpBall, w1, h1, null);

                // Method Responsible for ball movement and its position
                checkBallMovementAndPosition();

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            }

        }

        private void checkBallMovementAndPosition() {
            if (w1 < 0 && h1 < 0) {
                w1 = this.getWidth() / 2;
                h1 = this.getHeight() / 2;
            } else {
                w1 += w1_V;
                h1 += h1_V;

                if ((w1 > this.getWidth() - bm_w) || (w1 < 0)) {
                    w1_V = w1_V * -1;
                    w1 += w1_V;
                }

                if ((h1 > this.getHeight() - bm_h) || (h1 < 0)) {
                    h1_V = h1_V * -1;
                    h1 += h1_V;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}


Note: Replace the images with Your images.
```

Comment: i am waiting for past 1 hour no one can answer my question thank u for response.i am new for android,i am unable to handle this complex code,but i have to do this,if u don't mind will you modify my code.if u r free only otherwise i will try

Comment: Yeah! tav, I know that its a little complexed code specially for beginner. But if you have the knowledge of Canvas and how to use it, you can understand it.And if am not wrong its matching your requirement.

Comment: i am executed ur code i found 2 methods(bm_w = bmpTorch.getWidth();
        bm_h = bmpTorch.getHeight()) in mainactivity.i can't understand .will u please once execute my code

Comment: Damn! sorry about that, actually these are not 2 methods, they are actually getting the width and height of your ball. So you can replace bm_w=bmpBall.getWidth() and bm_h=bmpBall.getHeight()

Comment: A.R if u don't mind will u please once execute my code,if u do this help u helped a lot.thanks

Comment: <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
  android:duration="4000"
  android:fromXDelta="0%p"
  android:toXDelta="0%p"
  android:toYDelta="10%" 
  android:fromYDelta="0%"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
  android:repeatMode="reverse"
  
  />

Comment: later i have to do some modifications in animation.xml use this  for this time

Comment: A.R still i am waiting for ur response